# How do I get more detailed outputs about subnets?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using terraform, in our outputs file, we have the following:

```
output "eks_private_subnets" {
  description = "List of IDs of private subnets"
  value       = aws_subnet.eks.*.id 
}
```

I need to get more detail from this output. For example, I need "eks_private_subnets_in_zonea". We have three zones, zonea, zoneb, zonec, and this aws_subnet.eks resource produces two subnets in each zone, like so:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "eks" {
  count =  length(var.eks_private_subnets)

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.this[0].id
  cidr_block        = var.eks_private_subnets[count.index]
  availability_zone = element(var.azs, count.index)
....
}
```

Is there any mechanism that can look at the subnets created, interrogate them to see which zone they are in, and group the subnets by zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own output structure and grouping with a `locals` block. For example, this trick with [`transpose()`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/transpose) might work for what you need:

```
locals {
  subnet_to_az = {for subnet in aws_subnet.eks: subnet.id => [subnet.availability_zone]}
  az_to_subnet = transpose(local.subnet_to_az)
}

output "subnets_grouped_by_az" {
  value = local.az_to_subnet
}
```

Note that it is important that `subnet.availability_zone` is in a list (in `[]`), otherwise transpose won't work.